# Live views in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, xcode6

I successfully tried to the apply interface builder live views (as seen in the "What's new in interface builder" talk on the WWDC14) to the tutorial [How to make a custom control in swift](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76433/how-to-make-a-custom-control-swift) (@IBDesignable etc.)

I added a Framework (RangeSliderKit) which holds the custom control, added @IBDesignable to the class and when I added a UIView and set its custom class everything worked. The control was rendered live in interface builder.

But when I tried to add an outlet of the control to the ViewController I get an error: "Use of undeclared type 'RangeSlider'". I tried to import the Framework but I can't reference any of the defined classes. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? [XCode Project here](https://github.com/thestoneage/CustomRangeSlider). Version of Xcode used: Version 6.0 (6A313)

Answer (score 1):

IBDesignable doesn't support embedding frameworks as of Xocde 6.